# Room RxJava - onNext() called once in FlowableSubscriber

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, android-room

Following is my FlowableSubscriber code

```
fun getFlowableSubscriber(): FlowableSubscriber<List<Incoming>>{
    return object : FlowableSubscriber<List<Incoming>> {
        override fun onComplete() {
            log("onComplete")
        }

        override fun onSubscribe(subscription: Subscription) {
            log("onSubscribe")
            this@IncomingFragment.subscription = subscription
            subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE)

        }

        override fun onNext(items: List<Incoming>) {
            log("onNext item size is ${items.size}")      
        }

        override fun onError(t: Throwable?) {
            log("onError $t")

        }
    }
}
```

And my activity lifecycle methods:

```
 override fun onResume() { 
        if (::subscription.isInitialized){
            subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE) 
        }
        super.onResume()
    }


    override fun onStop() { 
        subscription.cancel()
        super.onStop()
    }
```

The problem is `onNext()` runs only once, I want it to trigger everytime `onResume()` is called. But the `subscription.request()` seem to work only once.
I am using this with Room.

Comment: I think you should consider using LiveData instead because it does this with 10% complexity

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yeah that was a big mistake on my part to choose Rx in first place.

Comment: You can't reuse a `FlowableSubscriber` or the `Subscription` to leak into the stop/resume. Once `cancel()` was called, no further data will be emitted so the `request` in resume will do nothing. You have to resubscribe to the source with a fresh `Subscriber`.

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks, that is exactly how I solved it.